# Find Delta when two columns have same value- sql server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a sql server table named pricechart like this:

```
Serial    Price    Volume    Id      Delta
1         3.2      280       1121    
2         4.6      700       4821    
3         1.1      120       5696
4         3.2      300       1121
5         3.2      412       1121
6         1.1      130       5696
```

I want to fill in the delta column in such a way that if the Price and Id are same, then I need the delta between the volumes. For instance, Delta in Row 4 should be 20 and Row 5 should be 12 and Row 6 should be 10.
The delta is difference between the current volume and the previous volume having the same price and id.

The data is in sql server.
What I tried so far:
Fetched the data from sql server to python. Created individual dictionaries for distinct ids and then find the delta.

I am pretty sure that is not the right way and need help if this could be done directly on sql server or maybe in pandas.

Comment: how would you `order` the data?

Comment: The data is ordered by a column called serial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You seem to have an ordering in mind, and that ordering needs to be represented as a column.

For this particular purpose, you seem to want lag:

```
select t.*,
       (volume - lag(volume) over partition by price, id order by serial) ) as volum_diff
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column or expression that specifies the ordering of the rows.

This will return `NULL` for rows that don't have a matching "previous" row.

Comment: I have just edited the question to add the serial column.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `LAG`:

```sql
SELECT *,
  Volume - LAG(Volume, 1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY Id, Price ORDER BY serial) AS Delta
FROM tab;
```